# imagemagick monochrome convert in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, imagemagick

I have an image in the iPhone that I need to convert to monochrome. The images are photographs of documents and I need as clean a conversion as I can get.

My first solution did a pixel for pixel compare with a threshold, and while it does the conversion fine, shadows can overwhelm the image.

My next trial is to use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), hoping that there are various noise reduction/despeckle filters that I can apply to clean the image up, which is what [this guy is doing](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/producing-a-good-fax-image-using-ghostscript-and-imagemagick-838614/).

I have [imagemagick running on the iPhone](http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2011/03/21/im-xcode4-ios4-3/) and can apply "[MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-wand.php)" methods with no problem. My issue is that I don't think there is one built in that will do what I want. So I turn to the [ConvertImageCommand](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/convert_8c.html) but am lost on how to actually use it.

So I am looking for any guidance or examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I've been looking for is [Adaptive Thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29#Adaptive_thresholding) in my conversion to monochrome.

[Chris Greening](http://www.cmgresearch.com/) has created an [image processing library](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) that handles this quite well.

So no imagemagick needed.