# What's the fastest way to create UIImage from NSData with custom height and width?

Tags: resize, uiimage, nsdata

I got a NSData, and I want to convert it to UIImage with custom height and width.
I know the way that use CGContextDrawImage or drawInRect to get resized image from CGContextRef. But it's too slow, Can I get a fast way to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this to get image from NSData:-

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

If you want to make a thumbnail of a UIImage (with proportional resizing or maybe some cropping involved), check out UIImage+Resize category that allows you to use concise, ImageMagick-like syntax:

```
UIImage* squareImage       = [image resizedImageByMagick: @"320x320#"];
```

Comment: where can I get the ImageMagick category?

Comment: from here *http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/*
Also you can see this post *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267432/using-the-c-api-for-imagemagick-on-iphone-to-convert-to-monochrome*