# how to implement magnetic lasso tool in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to edit a UIImage. I want to remove background of an image using magnetic lasso tool. I am not sure how to implement that and from where I have to start. Are there any third party libraries for magnetic lasso tool, if yes can anyone please provide me with the code or can someone please guide me for implementing magnetic lasso tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this library for the same what you want

it will remove Image Background

**Link :** https://github.com/ap4y/iMagickWand (Not Working)

Also there is one more link to achieve this by C API :

[Using the C API for ImageMagick (on iPhone?) to convert to monochrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267432/using-the-c-api-for-imagemagick-on-iphone-to-convert-to-monochrome)

Go through this stack link.

Comment: Yes I tried that code but it is not working it has still two issues open in the git.

Comment: I have update my answer please check that link its also useful for your requirement.

Comment: but I want to use lasso tool to remove background manually.@codeChanger